# Разбить лист предложений на слова

Tags: java

Есть метод:

```
public static String[] getSeparateWords() {
        List<Sentence> sentences = Logic.getQuestionSentences("la muu ma? bu bu. cu cu cu? muu?");
        String[] words =null;

        for (Sentence sentence: sentences) {
            words = sentence.getWords().split("[ ?,]");
        }
        return words;
    }
```

В нем есть метод, который возвращает лист вопросительных предложений. И эти все вопросительные предложения надо разбить на слова.

Проблема в том, что если использовать массив, только последнее предложение разбивается на слова. А нужны все предложения. Как это можно сделать?

Answer (score 0):

ArrayList strings - вот что помогло.